# How to get ROUTE_PATTERN from request in play 2.6 scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.6

I've extracted ROUTE_PATTERN in play 2.5 with:

```
request.tags.get("ROUTE_PATTERN")
```

now I updated play 2.6 and this code doesn't work anymore. I read play documentation here:
[What’s new in Play 2.6](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Highlights26)

I tried:

```
object Attrs {
    val RoutePattern: TypedKey[String] = TypedKey("ROUTE_PATTERN")
  }
  request.attrs.get(Attrs.RoutePattern)
```

It always returns None. How I can get the RoutePattern of request in play 2.6?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [2.6 migration guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Migration26#Router-tags-are-now-attributes):

> If you used any of the `Router.Tags.*` tags, you should change your code to use the new `Router.Attrs.HandlerDef` (Scala)....
>
> This new attribute contains a `HandlerDef` object with all the information that is currently in the tags. The current tags all correspond to a field in the `HandlerDef` object....

The field in `HandlerDef` that corresponds to the old `ROUTE_PATTERN` tag is [`path`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.routing.HandlerDef@path:String):

```
import play.api.routing.{ HandlerDef, Router }
import play.api.mvc.RequestHeader

val handler = request.attrs(Router.Attrs.HandlerDef)
val routePattern = handler.path
```

Comment: By the way, is there a doc page on default tags (not attributes) of the request? Not the migration page, but a dedicated one. Couldn't find such neither for 2.5 not for 2.6.